# is there a way to declare a variable with limited options?

Tags: java, variables

i'm trying write a variable *(e.g. private String colour)* but I want it to only be able to be black or white, as in my class diagram I have written it as *color:{Black,White}*. Is this something I can declare at this stage? If so how is this written?

Comment: Does it have to be a limited `String`, or are you willing to make a custom enum?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica it's meant to be a product listing, so there are only two colours available, so i think i can use a custom enum. do you think that is the better approach for me to use?

Comment: If this is part of a system with lots of different products, and each product has a different set of available colours, then an Enum is not the best choice.  You'd be better off to use some kind of `Set`, with `Color` objects (for example, from `java.awt.Color` if these are suitable) in the `Set`.  Then each product can use a different `Set` to limit the options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, if there are any constraints to be set on a field value, you can consider using Enum, which are a special class/type you can declare your variable to be in order to force it to accept a certain range of constant values. For your case,

Create an enum:

```
public enum Colour{
   BLACK,
   WHITE
}
```

Declarethe colour field like so:

```
private Colour productColour;
```

Assigning of value will look like this:

```
productColour = Colour.BLACK;
```

Comment: when I'm declaring a generic product class will i have to initialize two variables for black and white? (private Colour productColour = Colour.BLACK; and then private Colour productColour = Colour.WHITE;)?

Comment: No, typically you would declare it once for your class and initialize the value, whether its BLACK or WHITE after you create your object. I have edited my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 7):

Use `Enum`. For example:

```
public enum Color{
 WHITE, BLACK;
}
```

More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: i follow! i think this is what i was looking for, thank you!!